# How can I check whether multiple ports on multiple destinations are reachable from multiple hosts?

Tags: networking, firewall, port

*Hopefully, my title is correct and clear.*

I am facing a bit of a challenge and thought that asking for help from network engineers would be my best bet.

Let me start with this:

1. If I wanted to check (from my local machine) if a particular port is open on some host, I could do it this way: `telnet 1.2.3.4 80`
2. If I wanted to check (from my local machine) multiple hosts' and ports' reachability, I'd just keep substituting host IP and port number.

However, what if I need to specify source IP? In other words, I would love something like this:

`telnet source_ip destination_ip port_number`

Here is my problem:

1. I am using CentOS, and `telnet` does not have `-b` option.
2. I tried using `nc -s source_ip host_ip port` but it returns this error:

> bind: Cannot assign requested address

3. Another thing is that I need to check these ports programmatically because I have thousands of source IPs, thousands of destination IPs, and thousands of ports. I am currently doing it with Python, but I still did not find a way to specify source IP. As a result, I'd have to login to each host to run my script.

P.S. My table looks something like this:

```
Source, Destination, Port

1.1.1.1, 1.2.3.4, 80

2.2.2.2, 2.3.4.5, 443

2.2.2.2, 1.2.3.6, 443

and so on..
```

Comment: Apparently you want to spoof the source address? Perhaps you can do it with SNAT of iptables. But you wouldn't expect the replies to reach you. (You can `tcpdump` or so on the server though.)

Comment: If you are talking about using one of the actual IPs of the host, you should set up route properly.

Comment: @TomYan Ok I guess this is unfeasible then (without spoofing and other time consuming work). Do you think firewall APIs provide such checks?

Comment: "Without spoofing"? Eh, no, your question is _all about_ spoofing the source address... The SNAT option (or direct packet generation e.g. with scapy) would be feasible, but only if you're doing these checks from the victim's default gateway (maybe 1–2 levels up). Anything else just isn't going to work.

Comment: @TomYan Ok thanks. What about some programmatic ways? Are you familiar with anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

Sending packets with a custom source address is easy – the problem is that you need to *receive responses* that the target host would be sending to you. There is no way you can just say "pretend I'm 1.1.1.1, oh, but send the actual reply to 2.2.2.2 instead" and have it honored by arbitrary hosts across the internet.

So in short, you cannot do this over the internet.

However, this would work if you're doing these checks from a machine that is directly upstream of the target – in other words, from the machine's default gateway, which would be handling all responses no matter what destination they're for.

If the gateway machine is running Linux, you could:

- Use scapy or libpcap to directly craft and send the spoofed packets, similar to how nmap works.
- Add SNAT rules to iptables and let the kernel perform translation.
- Use the IP_TRANSPARENT socket option, which allows your program to bind to *any* local address it wants (this feature was meant for "transparent proxies").

Comment: Thanks for response, but I am not really a networking guy:) Is there a chance you can provide some example?